# Probability of choosing two 2-digit positive integers with the same units place

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random

Two natural numbers, each of which has 2 digits are chosen randomly.

What is the probability that these two numbers have the same unit digit?

The options were

$\frac{1}{9}$

$\frac{8}{89}$

$\frac{8}{90}$

$\frac{1}{10}$

**My attempt**

Total number of ways to select two 2-digit numbers = $90 \times 90$

Total pairs of numbers such that their unit place are the same =

unit place **zero** = $81$ :

$(10, 10), (10, 20), ... (10, 90)$

$(20, 10), (20, 20), ... (20, 90)$

$...$

$(90, 10), (90, 20), ... (90, 90)$

Unit place **one** = $81$

$(11, 11), (11, 21), ... (11, 91)$

$(21, 11), (21, 21), ... (21, 91)$

$...$

$(91, 11), (91, 21), ... (91, 91)$

.
.
.

etc for unit places $0 \to 9$

i.e. in total $81 \times 10 = 810$

So req ans = $\frac{810}{8100} = \frac{1}{10}$

**IS THIS CORRECT ?**

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE ! But  note that  this forum requires you to first show what you have tried and where you are stuck, so please edit in your efforts.

Comment: Can the numbers be the same?  Your $90 \times 90$ assumes so, but often they are not allowed to be.  It is the difference between sampling with and without replacement.  Your calculation is needlessly complicated but correct if you are sampling with replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your sampling is with replacement it is easier to note that the chance of each digit is $\frac 1{10}$.  You draw the first number and note the units digit.  The chance you get that units digit on the second draw is $\frac 1{10}$, so that is our answer.

Comment: Ah, +1. This is actually much simpler than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solution is correct, although your countings need just a bit more formal justification. Here is how you can formally write the solution.

There are $9\times 10$ ways to choose a 2-digit number ($9$ for the tens digit, $10$ for the tens digit). Then the number of ways to choose two 2-digit numbers is $9^2\times 10^2$.

Now, fix a units digit. This can be done in $10$ ways. Now you have the freedom of choosing any two tens digits, which can be done in $9^2$ ways. Thus your probability is $$\frac{9^2\times 10}{9^2\times 10^2}=\frac1{10}$$